# JFrame not revalidating

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, jpanel

My JPanel is not resizing to the window, I would at least like it to move to the center when resizing, the JTextArea does it just fine but I can't get the JPanel with my buttons in it to resize as well. Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package privatelessontracknetbeans;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


/**
 *
 * @author Brent C
 */
public class PrivateLessonsTrackerGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form PrivateLessonsTrackerGUI
 */
public PrivateLessonsTrackerGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    sun = new javax.swing.JButton();
    mon = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tue = new javax.swing.JButton();
    wed = new javax.swing.JButton();
    thu = new javax.swing.JButton();
    fri = new javax.swing.JButton();
    sat = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    addInstructors = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Private Lessons Tracker");

    jPanel1.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            jPanel1ComponentResized(evt);
        }
    });

    sun.setText("Sun");
    sun.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sunActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    mon.setText("Mon");
    mon.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            monActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    tue.setText("Tue");
    tue.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tueActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    wed.setText("Wed");
    wed.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            wedActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    thu.setText("Thu");
    thu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            thuActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    fri.setText("Fri");
    fri.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            friActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    sat.setText("Sat");
    sat.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            satActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(sun, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(mon, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tue)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(wed)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(thu)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(fri)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(sat)
            .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(sun)
                .addComponent(mon)
                .addComponent(tue)
                .addComponent(wed)
                .addComponent(thu)
                .addComponent(fri)
                .addComponent(sat))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMenuItem3.setText("Home");
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenuItem2.setText("Exit");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Instructor");

    addInstructors.setText("Add Instructor(s)");
    addInstructors.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addInstructorsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(addInstructors);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    jMenu3.setText("Student");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void addInstructorsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    AddingInstructorsGUI aiGUI = new AddingInstructorsGUI();
    aiGUI.setVisible(true);
}                                              

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void sunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("Sundays List");
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
}                                   

private void monActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("Mondays List");
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
}                                   

private void tueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("Tuesdays List");
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
}                                   

private void wedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("Wednesdays List");
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
}                                   

private void thuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("Thursdays List");
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
}                                   

private void friActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("Fridays List");
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
}                                   

private void satActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    jTextArea1 = new JTextArea("Saturdays List");
    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
}                                   

private void jPanel1ComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                         
    this.jPanel1.revalidate();
}                                        


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new PrivateLessonsTrackerGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem addInstructors;
private javax.swing.JButton fri;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JButton mon;
private javax.swing.JButton sat;
private javax.swing.JButton sun;
private javax.swing.JButton thu;
private javax.swing.JButton tue;
private javax.swing.JButton wed;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

This is just for the class I am having trouble with, if you try to run it you will have some errors. One more thing, I don't understand the need for high reputation to have certain Tags, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a FlowLayout with center alignment instead your GroupLayout.

```
jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

Comment: Its netbeans, can't change netbeans generated code, and I was hoping for someone to tell me how to do this in netbeans.